# Sass generated classes not getting applied

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom sass setup with bootstrap 5 and bunch of my own SCSS files, all of this gets compiled in style.css using gulp. I have a _colors.scss file which stores all the colors according to our design language. We use this to generate a bunch of classes that can be used any where to change colors:

```
// Text Colors
$colors: (
  "icon-color": $slate-500,
  'slate-10': $slate-10,
  'slate-40': $slate-40,
  'slate-300': $slate-300,
  "secondary": $secondary-text-color,
  "green": $green,
  "light-green": $green-color,
  "blue": $blue,
  "blue-200": $blue-200,
  "blue-300": $blue-300,
  "blue-400": $blue-400,
  "dodger-blue": $dodger-blue,
  "mariner-blue": $mariner-blue,
  "light-blue": $blue-100,
  "cadet-blue" : $cadet-blue,
  "aqua-10": $aqua-10,
  "gray": $gray,
  "gray-light": $gray-light,
  "light-gray": $gray-100,
  "bright-gray": $bright-gray,
  "gray-200": $gray-200,
  "clay": $clay,
  "clay-10": $clay-10,
  "mandy-pink": $mandy-pink,
  "aqua": $aqua,
  "violet": $violet,
  "white": $white,
  "primary": $primary-text-color
);

@each $color-name, $color-value in $colors {
  .text-#{$color-name} {
    color: $color-value !important;
  }

  .bg-#{$color-name} { 
    background-color: $color-value !important;
  }

  .border-#{$color-name} {
    border-color: $color-value !important;
  }
}
```

Problem is certain classes like `.text-gray` or `.text-blue` are not working. My guess is that since bootstrap also uses variables called `gray` and `blue`, its conflicting with my variables in _colors.scss.

On closer look, the css does gets generated properly (I found below declaration in final style.css):

```
.case-study .case-study-right .card .data-bar p:last-of-type,.share .social-media>span,.text-color-gray-200,.text-gray-200 {
    color: #69727A!important
}
```

But using `.text-gray` has no effect, the class is not getting applied.

How do I fix this? please help!

Comment: Please provide a code that can be easily tested, for example, a snippet we can run. I tried to compile your styles but the provided code includes references to variables like $slate-500 that are not defined.

Comment: Make sure you `import`/`link` bootstrap before your CSS file so that your CSS file overrides bootstrap styles

Comment: If you see the correct style for the correct selector in your dist CSS file, it should be applied (or at least visible in the chrome console on the element, is it the case?). If not, check that the CSS is valid. A wrong character could mess some part of it.

Comment: could You show me declaration of color $gray.  maybe it was omitted. Try to use gray:gray-200 for a sec and check.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're sure that you see the correct selector and the correct rule in your CSS file: it should be applied. And so, the rule should be visible in the browser console (even if overridden).

If you see it in your CSS file, but not applied in the browser console: check that your CSS file is valid (and that your gulp production script compiles fine), as a bad character could mess some part of it.

If you see your CSS in the browser console, but it's overridden by some bootstrap rules, you can override bootsrap variables, and change bootstrap colors by yours like so (import bootstrap before this):

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #121212,
  success: #8bcea8
  ...
);
```

You could also try this to replace bootstrap values by yours:

```
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simple answer is:

Use Bootstrap 5 the intended way!**

Bootstrap is a complex framework. All that huge number of classes work together including overwriting color settings if provided and used the intended way. In your code example you additional create helper classes Bootstrap would provide to you out of the box if you use it the Bootstrap way. As you did not do it leads to conflicts which are not easy to handle ... and nearly impossible to solve without to have the possibility to analyize the page itself.

This is what you may check:

**You may check: are there other classes which blocks your classes?**

In your example you use `!important` to get higher specifity. But the color is overwritten by other classes ...

Maybe that are Bootstrap which uses `!important` as well. In that case you can try to add your classes at the end of your CSS (after the Bootstrap classes) so they are able to overwrite in case of identical specifity.

Additional: in your example you added a huge bunch of non-bootstrap-classes. Maybe this individual added classes blocks your styling by adding a color with higher specifity (using `!important` as well which is not a good technique at all) to your element than your added class do.

In that case same solution may be possible ... but individual classes with `!important` and an additional higher specifity (i.e. using two class names in the selector) will win over your helper classes also your helper class comes later in your CSS file.

To be honest: most often analyzing such an huddle of classes indeed is only possible in the browser on the page direct using the developer tools.

**But best way indeed would be ...

Do a correct Bootstrap theming and use Bootstrap classes!!!**

1. You really don't need to create the helper classes on your own. Just do a SASS setup of Bootstrap ... and add your needed/additional colors **NOT (or not only)** to map `$colors` but **AS WELL TO** Bootstrap map `$theme-colors`. Bootstrap builds up helper-/utility-/elements-color-classes not on `$colors` but on `$theme-colors`. That means: doing that this intended way ... all your helper classes you added in your project on your own will be provided by Bootstrap mechanic in the correct order and avoiding conflicts to your CSS.
2. Use Bootstrap classes to style your page. Now you don't need to create an additional class `.case-study { color: gray }`. Just use the Bootstrap helper class and add `.text-gray` to same element. (Note: In your example you use the incredible number of **NINE** classes to do the same styling. In case 'text in cards' here is a nice hint how to realize it the bootstrap way: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#border).

**Just thinking about using complex Framework...**

Bootstrap is done to help you. As there is a lot of code using that Framework only makes sense to use the code as much as possible without writing new classes. So best way indeed to work with it is to use the Bootstrap elements and styling them the Bootstrap way. That makes it simple and avoids conflicts... And: you are able to do nearly everything with these elements.

And if you need to extend Bootstrap i.e. with additonal classes: `avoid (deep) nested classes` and `!important` as well so you are able to overwrite settings with simple helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

i had the similar problem it was my scss was successfully converted to the css but not applied, after checking for hours i found out ,i have written B capital while the class name was btn
so when everything is working then the problem is always in your code syntax!